# Macro with default text in user defined package

Tags: macros, package-writing

I made a package to replace my title page and it produces errors on compilation.

Here is a minimum example:

```
\ProvidesPackage{replacementTitle}[2017 Personal Title Package]
\newcommand*{\mynewmacro}[1]{\gdef\@mynewmacro{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@mynewmacro}{default text}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}
Text before \@mynewmacro\unskip\ and text after.
\end{titlepage}
}
\endinput
```

This produces two errors:

```
./main.tex:51: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   P
l.51 

./main.tex:51: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   P
l.51
```

This is due to the way that I define a macro which can optionally be set externally, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You don't give many clues, there is no `I` in the posted code, but the error is triggered on `I` however the optional argument of `\ProvidesPackage`, if it is used, has to start with a latex-format date 2017/03/01 ...

Comment: The optional argument to `\ProvidesPackage` should start with a date: `\ProvidesPackage{replacementTitle}[2017/03/07 Personal Title Package]`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks. I edited the original question so it produces the right error.